# Strange HDDSCAN results, consecutive bad blocks

Tags: hard-drive, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

I'm doing VR-Verify;

[image: Here are the results at 22%.]

All bads are **consecutive**, starting at around ~20-22%, and the percentage hasn't moved for the whole duration of bad blocks.

HDD was quite slow lately, especially on boot, could take up to 5-10 minutes to load every startup program, and takes about minute or two just to render desktop background after login. Save for slowness, never had major problems, but lately laptop was failing to properly wake up from sleep, so I decided to run the check and saw this.

Age ~4y, ~35K hours HDD on time.

Currently making a clone from disk image backups (incremental, never had failures due to unreadable drive yet)

Could it be that one bad block prevents further reading here and make every consecutive one fail?

I've also ran surface test from Hard Disk Sentinel, random reads this time, and at 10% it hasn't found single bad block.

Right now I'm thinking to stop the test and try several others; number of slow blocks is good enough indication by itself.

**Update**:

Ran `chkdsk /r` overnight, haven't noticed much in terms of errors, only that it couldn't write logs or something of that kind, but that may be due to the fact that I was running it from LiveUSB.

After booting up and retrying the test, I'm getting the same results pretty much:

[Bad blocks started at 22%, and I aborted the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbjc2.png)

Comment: If you get inconsistent results at various times & with different software, I'd change the SATA cable before running any more tests… or get the drive out & test it in a known-good enclosure.

Comment: I say results seem pretty consistent. It's a laptop as I said, but I have an adapter SATA/USB, so might play around with it later. Hopefully the backup image recovers and I'm able to boot from it

Comment: Depending on drive firmware it could be retrying to read or even remap sectors while your software has moved on. The drive being slow due to still dealing with the bad sector could be causing a timeout on other sectors. If the firmware then goes back to the original sector and starts again then you would see this. Have you tried any other tools? Hard drives aren't completely "dumb" devices with just a storage platter and conversion interface, there may well be some active intelligence in the controller and you are hitting an edge case where it fails weirdly.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue - hdtune shows 1 bad sector at around 50% of the disk surface and while hddscan also detected it, it also marked all following blocks as bad too. I switched to older version of hddscan (3.3) and it now only detects 1 bad block (same as hdtune), so it could be some bug in newer hddscan (4.1).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: It seems HDDScan cannot determine the end of a large 2TB disk and "places" bad sector beyound the end:) The disk on the pictures below is quite new and absolutely healthy:
This occures only during "Verify" tests. "Read" and "Erase" tests finished successfully.

[WD 2TB Disk:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2VIl.jpg)
[Verify test "beyond the last block"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yp2GK.jpg)
[All the blocks "beyond the end" are bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElgxQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this error, with a 1TB WD HDD, it might just be a user error:

[Launch it as Administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAUmx.png)

> I got this too. HDDScan shows every block is 'bad' when you don't
> launch it as Administrator. Yes, even if you're logged in as a user
> with Admin rights. You have to right-click HDDSCAN, then select 'Run
> as Administrator', then it will run properly.

Source: https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=31826
(September 21st, 2020, 16:11)